# Bootstrap dropdown-menu display:none after finish animation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have one button as drop-down menu and animation to show and hide dropdown.
How to check animation is finish and add style display:none to dropdown-menu

```css
.open>.dropdown-menu.dropdown-info {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0px;
}

.dropdown-menu.dropdown-info {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle " type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-info" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

I finally got your question, please check the below fiddle for how I implemented the one time animation effect.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Please let me know if this fixes your issue!

**Old:**

Does this satify your need?

By default leave (`display:none`) to the element, then set (`display:block`) when the menu is opened!

```css
.open > .dropdown-menu.dropdown-info {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu.dropdown-info {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle "  type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-info"  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @ArturBajak The problem is not clearly explained, By delete animation, what do you mean, in your question you have put something about adding `display:none` why is that?

Comment: when i click on buton then show dropdown menu animation, when i click again then show hide animation dropdown menu, when animation is ended then drodown-menu display as none

Comment: @ArturBajak Updated my answer please check

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dropdownSelectors = $('.dropdown');


function dropdownEffectData(target) {
 
  var effectInDefault = null,
      effectOutDefault = null;
  var dropdown = $(target),
      dropdownMenu = $('.dropdown-menu', target);
  var parentUl = dropdown.parents('ul.nav'); 


  if (parentUl.size() > 0) {
    effectInDefault = parentUl.data('dropdown-in') || null;
    effectOutDefault = parentUl.data('dropdown-out') || null;
  }
  
  return {
    target:       target,
    dropdown:     dropdown,
    dropdownMenu: dropdownMenu,
    effectIn:     dropdownMenu.data('dropdown-in') || effectInDefault,
    effectOut:    dropdownMenu.data('dropdown-out') || effectOutDefault,  
  };
}

// Custom function to start effect (in or out)
// =========================
function dropdownEffectStart(data, effectToStart) {
  if (effectToStart) {
    data.dropdown.addClass('dropdown-animating');
    data.dropdownMenu.addClass('animated');
    data.dropdownMenu.addClass(effectToStart);    
  }
}



// Bootstrap API hooks
// =========================
dropdownSelectors.on({
  "show.bs.dropdown": function () {
    // On show, start in effect
    var dropdown = dropdownEffectData(this);
    dropdownEffectStart(dropdown, dropdown.effectIn);
  },
  "shown.bs.dropdown": function () {
    // On shown, remove in effect once complete
    var dropdown = dropdownEffectData(this);
    if (dropdown.effectIn && dropdown.effectOut) {
      dropdownEffectEnd(dropdown, function() {}); 
    }
  },  
  "hide.bs.dropdown":  function(e) {
    // On hide, start out effect
    var dropdown = dropdownEffectData(this);
    if (dropdown.effectOut) {
      e.preventDefault();   
      dropdownEffectStart(dropdown, dropdown.effectOut);   
      dropdownEffectEnd(dropdown, function() {
        dropdown.dropdown.removeClass('open');
      }); 
    }    
  }, 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
 
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle "  type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-info " data-dropdown-in="slideInRight"  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

it i thinks is better solution